# .NET DefaultValue Property Attribute instantiate new custom object type

Tags: vb.net, attributes, default-value

I'm trying to use the DefaultValue attribute to decorate a property in order to assert the value is defaulted as a new list of a typed object in the program. The failing code is as follows:

```
<DataContract()>
Partial Public Class MessageBaseResponse


#Region "Properties"

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Header As Header


    <DataMember()>
    <DefaultValue(GetType(List(Of [Error])))>
    Public Property Errors As List(Of [Error])


    <DataMember()>
    <DefaultValue(GetType(List(Of Warning)))>
    Public Property Warnings As List(Of Warning)


#End Region

End Class
```

How to instantiate new lists as default property value using the DefaultValue attribute approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) attribute has more to do with serializing the data, not setting the actual default value of the property.  The linked page notes:

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

Try instantiating the lists with the "New" keyword:

```
Public Property Errors As New List(Of [Error])
```

Comment: Thank you. My current work around was - Public Property Errors As List(Of [Error]) = New List(Of [Error]) - which boils down to the same thing. I guess was just trying to see if there was a way to do it through an attribute, but you answer explains the details of that. Again, thanks @LarsTech